# Unable to detect adb version

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I can't upload apk from Android studio to connected device, because IDE cannot connect to adb. I see `Unable to detect adb version` errors in logs. I'm not sure what exactly caused the issue, but it worked yesterday.

Now I have:

- Windows 7
- Android studio 3.5 installed
- Platform tools 29.0.3 installed
- Both general and project settings in Android studio set to correct directory of android sdk (C:\dev\android_sdk)
- ANDROID_HOME is set to same sdk folder,
- PATH set to C:\dev\android_sdk\platform-tools\
- When I use `adb version` from cmd and Android Studio terminal, I get `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41`
- Also, `adb devices` shows my connected device

But, when I open Android Studio, the device is not visible. And I see a lot of errors in Event Log tab: `Unable to detect adb version`.

This is the log from Android studio logs:

```
2019-09-11 14:38:16,948 [ thread 12]   INFO - roid.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: C:\dev\android_sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe 
2019-09-11 14:38:17,251 [ thread 12]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - Unable to detect adb version
```

It also worth to mention that initially I tried to resolve duplicate adb conflict, as I had HTC Sync Manager installed, which had it's own adb, and it sometimes clashed with sdk/platform-tools adb. So I deleted HTC Sync, and adb version error occured. I have no idea why, because I couldn't find any settings that reference HTC adb location.

Comment: try to kill all the `adb.exe` processes from `Task Manager` in `Windows 7` and reconnect your device and `Allow USB Debugging` with `MTP Connection`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't helped. In fact, I believe there is a problem in connection between Android Studio and adb. As I mentioned, `adb devices` shows connected device.

Comment: You can try deleting your old `Android-SDK` folder and download a fresh one with restarting your system also.

Comment: I tried to completely re-install Android Studio along with sdk - no result :(

Comment: Is there adb installed in machine other than Android SDK. many time Mobile drivers or utility application installs adb and add them in to system path

Comment: `where adb.exe` returns single path to correct adb location.

Comment: See if storage is OK. Then update the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing adb.exe with adb from platform-tools 28.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I try to downgrade the version of platform-tools, then I solved.
I don't know why it's useless when I use platform-tools 29.0.5.
I'm under Windows 10, Android Studio 3.5.3.
Go to this site to download the old version -- https://www.androiddevtools.cn/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were missing dll files inside
`C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` after resetting my computer. Copying all the dll files from `C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows.old\Windows\SysWOW64` into their respective new folders(system32 and SysWOW64) worked for me.